# Tomcat don't run sakai on browser

Tags: java

I've followed the instructions of [Sakai 11 install guide](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=106792022)
and get cloned from their [github](https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai.git) repository

**This is my current configuration:**

1. **$ java -version**

   `java version "1.8.0_151"<br/> Java(TM) SE
    Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12) Java HotSpot(TM)
    64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)`
2. **$ git --version** 
    git version 1.8.3.1
3. $ mvn --version 
    Apache Maven 3.5.2
   (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d;
   2017-10-18T13:28:13+05:30)
    Maven home:
   /usr/local/apache-maven-3.5.2
    Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor:
   Oracle Corporation
    Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre
   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name:
   "linux", version: "3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family:
   "unix"
4. Apache Tomcat8.0.33
5. mysql --version
    mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux
   (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

**Install and deploy Sakai is "BUILD SUCCESS"**
I entered following command "**mvn clean install sakai:deploy -Dmaven.tomcat.home=/opt/tomcat**"

> ```
> [INFO] sakai-usermembership-impl .......................... SUCCESS [  0.267 s]
> [INFO] sakai-usermembership-pack .......................... SUCCESS [  0.157 s]
> [INFO] sakai-usermembership-tool .......................... SUCCESS [  1.939 s]
> [INFO] Sakai Web Project .................................. SUCCESS [  0.238 s]
> [INFO] sakai-web-api ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.392 s]
> [INFO] sakai-web-impl ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.306 s]
> [INFO] sakai-web-pack ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.170 s]
> [INFO] sakai-web-tool ..................................... SUCCESS [  1.023 s]
> [INFO] sakai-web-portlet .................................. SUCCESS [  1.480 s]
> [INFO] Sakai WebServices Project .......................... SUCCESS [  0.117 s]
> [INFO] Sakai Soap (CXF) ................................... SUCCESS [ 10.188 s]
> [INFO] Sakai base pom ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.145 s]
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time: 23:43 min
> [INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-11T11:18:09+05:30
> [INFO] Final Memory: 521M/1238M
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [akshay@localhost sakai]$
> ```

**then start tomcat but open browser and navigate to http://localhost:8080/portal got a error "HTTP Status 404 - /portal"(description: The requested resource is not available)**

**following logs file in /tomcat/logs** 
**catalina.2017-12-20.log**

```
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.411 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/opt/tomcat/lib/ehcache-terracotta-2.6.11.jar] from classloader hierarchy
 java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:47)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:36)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback.scan(TldScanner.java:301)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:313)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:245)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:106)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.416 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 58 ms
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.419 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.513 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.514 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 70603 ms
```

**host-manager.2017-12-20.log**

```
[akshay@localhost logs]$ sudo cat host-manager.2017-12-20.log 
20-Dec-2017 09:08:39.040 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-Dec-2017 09:23:57.632 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.355 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[akshay@localhost logs]$
```

**localhost.2017-12-20.log**

```
20-Dec-2017 11:37:01.805 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20-Dec-2017 11:37:01.915 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-Dec-2017 11:37:01.917 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter sakai.request
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sakaiproject.util.RequestFilter.init(RequestFilter.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5277)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

20-Dec-2017 11:37:02.003 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-Dec-2017 11:37:02.081 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.275 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.279 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.279 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
[akshay@localhost logs]$
```

**localhost_access_log.2017-12-20.txt**

```
[akshay@localhost logs]$ sudo cat localhost_access_log.2017-12-20.txt 
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Dec/2017:11:37:04 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11250
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Dec/2017:11:37:04 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Dec/2017:11:39:20 +0530] "GET /portal HTTP/1.1" 404 1006
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Dec/2017:11:40:11 +0530] "GET /portal HTTP/1.1" 404 1006
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Dec/2017:11:40:11 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
[akshay@localhost logs]$
```

**manager.2017-12-20.log**

```
[akshay@localhost logs]$ sudo cat manager.2017-12-20.log 
20-Dec-2017 09:08:39.104 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-Dec-2017 09:23:57.742 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.415 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[akshay@localhost logs]$
```

**catalina.out**

```
[akshay@localhost logs]$ tail -f ./catalina.out
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.416 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 58 ms
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.419 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.513 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Dec-2017 11:37:03.514 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 70603 ms
```

**Please, can anyone solve this problem?**

Comment: Can you try running this command "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true sakai:deploy" then start your tomcat server.

Comment: sir,tried this also.

Comment: Can you check your tomcat installation whether app is deployed or not? Go to webapps inside your tomcat and see if there is a folder called "portal".

Comment: checked sir , in tomcat/webapps portal folder available

Comment: Then check the logs, the app might not have deployed properly.

Comment: **i am checking 'catalina.2017-12-12.log' file**

Comment: **this error is occur  :**                                                                               > 12-Dec-2017 15:13:47.631 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
> 12-Dec-2017 15:13:47.632 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/portal] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: See few lines above this line.

Comment: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

12-Dec-2017 16:35:03.795 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-54] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

Comment: Its very difficult to identify the issue with these lines. Can you put the stacktrace in your question?

Comment: @santosh sir, what mean by stacktrace?

Comment: @Santosh I can't see a folder 'portal' in webapps, how can I get 'portal'?